# How can I allocate a pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Hello so I have a question about pointers. How would I allocate memory for a pointer in c++? Can I use the `new` keyword like I would with allocating a type? Also what is the advantage of using pointers in c++ instead of just passing through a variable? Does it increase the efficiency of a program?

Comment: You bette not use raw pointers at all. C++ has [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and [container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) that should cover your needs for dynamic memory management.

Comment: All answers to these and other questions you can find almost in any good textbook for C++.

Comment: Some people disagree with with my premise here, but based upon my experience and the question you pose, you would do well to first work on C, for which your question still mostly applies.  Once you know C pretty well, then you can take on C++, which I estimate to be require 5-10 times the difficulty.  I learned C from the Kernighan book, but any C book will do.  Come back to C++ in two months after a decent C book.   C++ is a marvelously powerful but astoundingly difficult beast.  Avoid learning in a Windows compiler, because most books on C assume a Unix-like environment.  Good luck!

Comment: @JohnGriffin *Once you know C pretty well, then you can take on C++, which I estimate to be require 5-10 times the difficulty.* -- Add to that difficulty the unlearning of a lot of that `C`.  If the goal is to learn C++, learn C++.

Answer (score 3):

> How would I allocate memory for a pointer in c++?

The same way you'd allocate memory for any other object - by creating one, either as a local variable, a global or static variable, or with dynamic allocation (directly or indirectly). For example, if you write this somewhere in a function:

```
int* pointerToInt;
```

it declares a local pointer to an `int` (but no `int` in particular, until you assign it).

> Can I use the new keyword like I would with allocating a type?

You can create a pointer in any of the same ways you'd create any other object (because pointers are objects). That includes by using `new`:

```
int** pointerToHeapAllocatedPointerToInt = new int*;
```

> Also what is the advantage of using pointers in c++ instead of just passing through a variable?

Pointers do different things to variables. What's the advantage of using a house address instead of a house? Well, I can give my house address to other people but I can't give them my house. But I can't sleep in my house address.

> Does it increase the efficiency of a program?

No, it decreases it.
Sometimes it decreases it less than the alternative.